# Как узнать программно, установлен ли оригинальный Google play или пиратский с модом?

Tags: android

Данный вопрос интересует, т.к. пиратский **google play** ломает проверку лицензии. Если явно не знаете метода, то хоть подскажите, куда двигаться, по каким критериям можно проверить и чтобы без root. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно проверить подписи соответствующих пакетов, соответствуют ли они оригинальным. Соответственно, это покажет, не был ли `apk` перепакован.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но я не совсем понимаю, о каких подписях идёт речь, можно поконкретнее?  
Если я вас правильно понял, то вы говорите о hashcod-е приложения по имени пакета? Если вы об этом, то как мне узнать "оригинальный" hashcod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двигайтесь в этом направлении. У каждого приложения из маркета подпись на всех устройствах одинаковая, далее становится все очевидно ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578871/how-to-get-app-signature